Using Highcharts with NextJS, The time (not the date) is repeating
I have a requirement to load datapoints within a given start and end time, for a given range of values. I used linspace to distribute the epochs between the range.

I had manually checked and coded to see if there are any duplicate values (which doesn't make sense), naturally there wasn't any.

I'm using a basic time series plotting with x axis being an epoch and y axis with numerical values, which are then customised according to the timezone.
I tried upgrading from 11.3.0 to "highcharts": "11.4.8", but no luck strangely this is happening for only one single instance.

Can you send the code as a demo in the online editor or the chart configuration? It can be simplified. Without it it's hard to help you. It's possible that it's a matter of setting the formatting of the X-axis labels, but it's hard to guess.

It's actually not an issue but a feature, related to timezon daylight savings time.

It's actually not an issue, but a feature, related to daylight savings time.
